# New to PHP; why am I getting a 500 error?

Tags: php, internal-server-error

I'm trying to make a PHP script that pulls records from a database and displays them on Bootstrap cards.  However, when I try to run the page the script is on, I get a 500 error; removing the script from the page resolves the error.  This is what I have (certain fields redacted for obvious reasons):

```
<?php
try {
    $link = new \PDO("mysql:host=[REDACTED];dbname=[REDACTED];charset=utf8mb4", "[REDACTED]", "[REDACTED]", array(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, \PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false));

    $handle = $link->prepare("SELECT expack, tier, raidName, picPath, bosses, downedBossesNormal, downedBossesSavage FROM raids WHERE expack = 4 ORDER BY tier DESC");

    $handle->execute();

    $result = $handle->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    print("<div class=\"card-columns\">")

    foreach($result as $row) {
        print("<div class=\"card\"><img class=\"card-img-top\" src=\"");
        print($row->picPath);
        print("\"><div class=\"card-header\"><h4 class=\"card-title\">");
        print($row->raidName);
        print("</h4>");
    }
}
catch(\PDOException $ex) {
    print($ex->getMessage());
}
?>
```

Out of the SQL fields mentioned, `raidName` and `picPath` are `varchar` fields, and the others are all `int` fields.

Since this is my first ever PHP project, I probably did something stupid to cause this 500 error; I just don't know what it was.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Did you check your logs?

Comment: Beyond the linked duplicates about enabling error reporting, always look in web server logs for generic 500 errors, regardless of what the server is doing.

Comment: I looked in the error logs on CPanel; they're empty.  If there's another place I can look, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ask your server admin.  Fatal PHP errors should show up in the error log unless they have configured it differently.  Beyond that, you should always enable error reporting during development.

Comment: I will do that then.  How do I enable error reporting in PHP, by the way?

Comment: Read the linked duplicates.

Comment: Thank you.  Now I have a plan on where to go next.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180897/discussion-between-psduckie-and-devon).